# How to update an immutable file with Ansible

Tags: file, ansible

Trying to update an immutable file (on a filesystem that supports attributes) with Ansible fails with the following error.

```
Operation not permitted
```

Also see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/48886

**Example Task**

```
- name: example
  template:
    src: example.j2
    dest: /some/example
    attributes: '+i'
```

So far I have come up with the following options to handle this, each with a drawback.

**Option 1)**

drawback: both tasks always change the file on every run

```
- name: Make example mutable (so changes can be applied)
  file:
    path: /some/example
    attributes: '-i'
- name: Deploy example
  template:
    src: example.j2
    dest: /some/example
    attributes: '+i'
```

**Option 2)**

drawback: the initial error is shown which might be confusing and it has code duplication

```
- name: Handle example changes
  block:
    - name: Deploy example
      template:
        src: example.j2
        dest: /some/example
        attributes: '+i'
  rescue:
    - name: Make example mutable (so changes can be applied)
      file:
        path: /some/example
        attributes: '-i'
    - name: Deploy example
      template:
        src: example.j2
        dest: /some/example
        attributes: '+i'
```

So how should a task like this be implemented to successfully apply changes without any error?

Answer (score 1):

i believe the source of your problem is the fact you work on /tmp Filesystem.

`template` module documentation states about the attributes:

> To get supported flags look at the man page for chattr on the target system.

I played on my linux box with chattr command and here is the difference in behavior:

```
[root@greenhat-34 ~] > cd /tmp
[root@greenhat-34 tmp] > touch file1
[root@greenhat-34 tmp] > chattr +i file1
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on file1
[root@greenhat-34 tmp] > lsattr file1
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on file1
[root@greenhat-34 tmp] > cd /
[root@greenhat-34 /] > touch file2
[root@greenhat-34 /] > chattr +i file2
[root@greenhat-34 /] > lsattr file2
----i--------------- file2
[root@greenhat-34 /] > rm file2 
rm: remove regular empty file 'file2'? y
rm: cannot remove 'file2': Operation not permitted
[root@greenhat-34 /] > chattr -i file2 
[root@greenhat-34 /] > rm file2       
rm: remove regular empty file 'file2'? y
[root@greenhat-34 /] >
```

seems that chattr cant work on `tmpfs` FS.

**TL/DR:**

If you generate those files in a regular directory - for example: `/testdir` - instead of `/tmp`, you should be good to go.

Comment: Good catch. The detail of using "/tmp" in the example seems to have been misleading. I did not properly support the described "update an immutable file" problem. The assumption is for sure a filesystem with attribute support. I have to slightly update the example then.